# How to generate and insert primary key when using SELECT DISTINCT in OracleDB?

Tags: oracle, database-design, select, insert, distinct

How do I insert (or generate and insert) a primary key when I use the `SELECT DISTINCT` query?

If I have a table made like this:

```
CREATE TABLE testUser(
    username VARCHAR2(50 CHAR),
    email VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
)
```

And I had some table `customer_orders` with this data I could quickly populate this using:

```
INSERT INTO testUser(username, email)
SELECT DISTINCT user_name, user_email
FROM customer_info;
```

However if instead I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
   id NUMBER,
   user_name VARCHAR2(50 CHAR),
   user_email VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
)
```

and try to use the same method (the `SELECT DISTINCT INSERT` method) I'll get an error like `ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("MYDB"."USERS"."ID")`.

This makes sense since the primary key is null, how can I autogenerate a primary key `1-n` where `n` is the `COUNT(SELECT DISTINCT user_name)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the database generate it for you (identity column, 12c feature):

```
CREATE TABLE users(
   id NUMBER generated always as identity, -- <= HERE
   user_name VARCHAR2(50 CHAR),
   user_email VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
);
```

If you are still on a version below 12c, then you can simply use `rownum`:

```
INSERT INTO testUser(id, username, email)
SELECT rownum, sq.* from
(select DISTINCT user_name, user_email
FROM customer_info) sq;
```

Or a sequence:

```
create sequence s1;
INSERT INTO testUser(id, username, email)
SELECT s1.nextval, sq.* from
(select DISTINCT user_name, user_email
FROM customer_info) sq;
```

Or a trigger, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle

Comment: You need to add `ON NULL` to the `IDENTITY` clause so that APEX Automatic DML Process will work.

Comment: @MichaelKutz as in `id number generated as identity on null`?

Comment: it is actually `id number generated by default ON NULL as identity`.  The Application Express [APEX] process sends a NULL value for new rows.  The `ON NULL` flag allows the `IDENTITY` value to be set even when a `NULL` value is part of the `INSERT` statement.  Try  `INSERT INTO T (id) VALUES (null)` on a table with the `ON NULL` flag and again without it.